# How to edit /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml (using minikube)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I want to add those flags : **--insecure-port=8080 and insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0** so I need to edit this file :**/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml**. However, I've done some research and I've found out that I should run this command: **minikube ssh**. After that, when I found the file and when I try to edit it I get **sudo: nano command not found** .

vim didn't work as well although I tried to install them but i got a whole bunch of errors.

Answer (score 1):

After running `minikube ssh` command and switching to sudo mode by `sudo -i`, you can install editor to the ubuntu base using:
`sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y vim-tiny`

P.S: For me vim-tiny worked well and then I could able to edit the `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` file using vim commands.

There is also a closed [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8393) on Minikube on this topic.